# Delete Music File Metadata Tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, metadata, flac, mutagen

How do I delete a metadata tag from a FLAC file or MP3 ID3 tag? I can use [mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) to edit information, but how would I delete a single portion of information?

I need to delete a tag entitled `fmps_playcount`, but not the rest of the metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ID3 tags you can remove a frame with delall.  For example:

```
>>> print audio.pprint()
TPE1=Agalloch
TALB=The Mantle
TRCK=1/9
TIT2=A Celebration For The Death Of Man...
TCON=Metal
>>> audio.delall('TCON')
>>> print audio.pprint()
TPE1=Agalloch
TALB=The Mantle
TRCK=1/9
TIT2=A Celebration For The Death Of Man...
```

For deleting the FLAC metadata (I do not have any FLAC files to test this on), I have a good feeling about:

```
>>> del audio['tag_to_delete']
```

Since the help documentation has:

```
 |  __delitem__(self, key)
 |      Delete a metadata tag key.
 |      
 |      If the file has no tags at all, a KeyError is raised.
```

You can read more about the delitem magic method here:    http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

Comment: this works for ID3 tags like you outlined- thanks. But I also need to do the same for flac files.